# Subtract Every Digit Of 2 Numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, matrix, iostream

Lets say an integer `array[2][1] = 6465;`
                    `array[3][1] = 5124;`

How can I subtract every digit of `array[2][1]` with `array[3][1]` using a loop,
for example:

```
6465
5124
=
1341
```

,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int val = array[2][i]  - array[3][i];
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are those 2 arrays holding different names?

Comment: @Steephen  no, the same name

Comment: Firstly array[2][1] and array[3][1] are not arrays but elements of a 2d array. Anyhow, what do you mean how to subtract them? You did subtract them in your for loop and printed the result. Do you want to store the result somewhere? What is that you want?

Comment: @matt s  I want to subtract the numbers digit by digit ..  
take the first digit from number#1 is (6)
and  digit from number#2 is (5)
subtract  them = 1
, etc for the whole numbers .. I dont want to subtract  the whole number#1 with number#2

Answer (score 0):

oIf I understand what are you looking for, you should declare the "numbers" like this:

```
unsigned char number[3][4] = {{6,4,6,5},
                              {5,1,2,4},
                              {0,0,0,0}}; // 3 numbers of 4 digits
```

And then do the subtraction with a loop, storing the result in the third element.
You should take care of the sign too...